# ColdFusion Code as failing on if condition

Tags: coldfusion

Working with cfscript code in ColdFusion, The following seems correct to me, if client_discount is either 0 or NULL, just do not generate the UniqueKey, use existing else use new one. But it does work somehow, I am not sure what I am missing here, trying different cflib UDF's also:

Here is my code:

```
f = structnew();
f.discountoffered = '#arguments.structform.client_discount#';
writedump(arguments);
result = structFindKeyWithValue(f,f.discountoffered,"0","ALL");
writedump(result);

if((arguments.structform.client_discount EQ 0) 
    OR (arguments.structform.client_discount NEQ "")) { 
    f.orderunique = generateRandomKey();
}
else {
   f.orderunique = '#arguments.structform.orderunique#';
}
```

Comment: "Does not work" is vague.  Please be more specific.

Comment: Yeah, I agree with Dan... what are you expecting, what are you getting instead, what troubleshooting have you done, etc...?

Comment: 'NULL' is kind of weird in ColdFusion. You could use `PARAM` to set `arguments.structForm.client_discount` to 0 if it does not exist and then just check if it is 0. And, when you are setting `f.discountOffered`, you do not need to use `'` and `#`. Just use the variable name.

Comment: You may want to read [Ask]. It has some good tips on what information to provide when asking questions.

Answer (score 1):

NULL is kind of wonky in ColdFusion.

I would handle this by paraming the value so it gets a value I decide if it does not exist.

Add this code under `f = structNew()` - or at the beginning of the function, does not really matter.

```
param name="arguments.structForm" default="#structNew()#;
param name="arguments.structForm.client_discount" default="0";
```

This way if client_discount is not present, it is set to 0 - the first line is to make sure that `structform` exists in arguments and if not, sets it to an empty struct.

Then your `if` statement need only check if it is 0.

```
if( arguments.structForm.client_discount == 0 ){
    f.orderunique = generateRandomKey();
}
else{
    f.orderunique = arguments.structform.orderunique;
}
```

Of course...you would need to verify that `arguments.structForm.orderunique` exists before using it.

Comment: Hi Acott, I am using coldfusion 9 and i am not sure it works, but i tried in version 11 and it does not seems to solve the issue..

Comment: I do not think it will matter - everything I posted should be compatible with ColdFusion 9.

Comment: @SaberTooth - In your description you say `NULL` (ie undefined), but your code checks for an empty string ie "". As mentioned in the comments, those are two totally different things. Which one is it?

Answer (score 1):

I think that's what you are trying to do

```
<cfscript>
f = structnew();
    if(not isnull(arguments.structform.client_discount)){
      f.discountoffered = '#arguments.structform.client_discount#';
      result = structFindKeyWithValue(f,f.discountoffered,"0","ALL");
       if((arguments.structform.client_discount EQ 0))
        f.orderunique = generateRandomKey();
         else
        f.orderunique = '#arguments.structform.orderunique#';
    }
else {
     f.orderunique = '#arguments.structform.orderunique#';
}
</cfscript>
```